# Why doesn't the button border get lighter than #f0f0f0?

Tags: html, css

I want to show some buttons with a "faded" look if they are disabled. (Forget the disabled aspect for now; I'm just worried about the style.) But if I try to make the `border-color` lighter, it doesn't seem to work. Buttons c4 and c5 are supposed to have borders which are #f8f8f8 or #ffffff but they get darker. What's going on, and how can I fix this?

Chrome: [image]

Firefox: [image]

```html
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
input[type=button].c1 {
  border-color: #808080;
}
input[type=button].c2 {
  border-color: #c0c0c0;
}
input[type=button].c3 {
  border-color: #f0f0f0;
}
input[type=button].c4 {
  border-color: #f8f8f8;
}
input[type=button].c5 {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="plain">
<input type="button" value="c1" class="c1">
<input type="button" value="c2" class="c2">
<input type="button" value="c3" class="c3">
<input type="button" value="c4" class="c4">
<input type="button" value="c5" class="c5">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default `border-style` is `inset` in **user agent stylesheet**

You need to set `border-style` as well Like

```
input[type=button].c4 {
    border-color: #f8f8f8; 
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Or you can use

```
input[type=button]{border: 1px solid}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    input[type=button] {
      border-style: solid;
    }

    input[type=button].c1 {
      border-color: #808080;
    }

    input[type=button].c2 {
      border-color: #c0c0c0;
    }

    input[type=button].c3 {
      border-color: #f0f0f0;
    }

    input[type=button].c4 {
      border-color: #f8f8f8;
    }

    input[type=button].c5 {
      border-color: #ffffff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="button" value="plain">
  <input type="button" value="c1" class="c1">
  <input type="button" value="c2" class="c2">
  <input type="button" value="c3" class="c3">
  <input type="button" value="c4" class="c4">
  <input type="button" value="c5" class="c5">
</body>

</html>
```